# Angular unit testing, for Observable errors

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am trying to errors in code coverage for service calls.
I am following two approaches but doing some mistake.

below is my method for which I am writing test cases

```
setPrefixSuffixDetails(): void {
    this.prefixSuffixDetailSubscription = this.profileBeneficiaryService.getPrefixSuffixDetails()
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data.body.prefixlist.length > 0) {
          this.prefixConfig.options = data.body.prefixlist;
        }
        if (data.body.suffixlist.length > 0) {
          this.suffixConfig.options = data.body.suffixlist;
        }
      }, error => {
        this.loadingData = false;
        this.notificationService.addNotications(error);
      });
  }
```

For testing, I am creating providers, below are my providers

```
 { provide: ProfileBeneficiaryService, useClass: ProfileServiceStub},
{provide: ProfileBeneficiaryService, useClass: ProfileBenficiaryErrorStub},
```

one is for success call and other is for error call.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({ .............

    class ProfileBenficiaryErrorStub {
            getPrefixSuffixDetails = function () {
                return Observable.throw(Error('Test error'));
            }}

     class ProfileServiceStub {
      getPrefixSuffixDetails = function () {
                return Observable.of(this.data);
            }
            }
```

But the issue is when I use two providers it only covers for error, If I dont include the provider for error, it covering for success

Please let me know where I am doing mistake using providers.

Also, I was trying to use spyOn way and facing error

```
 it('should check for the getPrefixSuffixDetails error call ', () => {
 spyOn(ProfileBeneficiaryService,'getPrefixSuffixDetails').and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));});
```

Comment: You don't need to use two providers, one is enough. `spyOn(ProfileBeneficiaryService,'getPrefixSuffixDetails').and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));});` should be enough to make a call to `profileBeneficiaryService.getPrefixSuffixDetails()` fails. If you post the test that you are writing for `setPrefixSuffixDetails` I could help you more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below solution worked for me

```
it('should check for the getPrefixSuffixList error call ', () => {
    spyOn(profileDependentsService, 'getPrefixSuffixList').and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));
    component.getPrefixSuffixList();
    expect(profileDependentsService.getPrefixSuffixList).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```